# How to search phone number from mongodb by any format using angular 8

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular8

want to search data from db but data saved in any format like this inputs like any format numbers in between slash or dash or space how to commonly search records can anyone tell how to search like this records(800) 123 1234 , 800-100-1000

Comment: What do the documents in the collection look like?

Comment: the collection may contain (801) 123 1234 or 801/123/1234 or 801-123-1234 or 801.123.1234